# Is it possible to make a window invisible to clicking in fluxbox?

Tags: window-manager, fluxbox

I'd like to display a few things "on top" of everything else, but making it click-through-able (Conky, or a video player, for instance).  Is this possible in fluxbox?  Or even in another window manager?